# define hyperlink using cells

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, cells

I have a list of cells that need to be linked to various cells in the same workbook. I was not able to find how to define a hyperlink using the "cell" property.

recorded this macro

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "Sheet3!A1", TextToDisplay:="#Sheet3!A4"
```

and tried to modify to

```
 ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        sheets("sheet3").cells(1,1),TextToDisplaysheets:="sheet3".cells(1,1).value
```

It does not work. I obviously miss something.

Answer (score 0):

To get to **cells(1,1)**

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim saddy As String
    saddy = "Sheet3!" & Cells(1, 1).Address(0, 0)
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        saddy, TextToDisplay:=saddy
End Sub
```

You can make a different string for the text to display if you like.